# Why does using this user defined function within print output none?

Tags: python, object, printing

```
def rev_sort(thelist):
    '''
    Reverses and then sorts the list entered
    '''
    thelist.sort()
    thelist.reverse()

def main():
    thelist = ["fun", "is", "programming"]
    # rev_sort(thelist)
    print(rev_sort(thelist))
    
main()
```

Calling main here outputs None, however, if I instead first use the function rev_sort and print the resulting list I get the decided output. However, I would expect it to be fine to do it like this, what's going on?

Comment: The function is not returning the new list, it is changing the list in place

Comment: Do you realize that you are doing `in-place` sorting by calling - `.reverse()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rev_sort(thelist):
    '''
    Reverses and then sorts the list entered
    '''
    thelist.sort()  # sort function return None
    thelist.reverse()  # reverse function returns None.
    return thelist  # you need to return the list back to main. 

def main():
    thelist = ["fun", "is", "programming"]
    print(rev_sort(thelist))
    
main()
```